# How i can implement modal on button click in laravel splade package

Tags: laravel

i am using laravel splade, and here is my test project, i want to implement a modal on button click how i can do that, here is my code,

```
<x-layout>
    <x-panel>
    <h1>Today's news items</h1>
   
    <x-splade-toggle>
       
        <button @click.prevent="toggle">Toggle notifications</button>
     
        <x-splade-lazy show="toggled">
            @php
        
            $notifications = [
                'Got a news about laravel splade',
                'Got a news about laravel splade this is best',
            ];
            
            @endphp
            <x-slot:placeholder>
                <p>Loading notifications...</p>
            </x-slot:placeholder>
     
            @foreach($notifications as $notification)
                <h1>{{ $notification }}</h1>
            @endforeach
        </x-splade-lazy>
    </x-splade-toggle>
</x-panel>
</x-layout>
```

I tried searching on google and forums but I didn't find any solutions. if anybody know about Laravel splade please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: (use Splade's "Link")

```
  <Link href="{{ route('newsitem.add') }}" modal>Add News Item</Link>
```

Then in your blade view, wrap your form in

```
 <x-splade-modal>  </x-splade-modal>
```

tags.